# Porting JavaScript function VB.NET

Tags: javascript, vb.net

I'm trying to port this seemingly simple JavaScript function to VB.NET:

```
function getFractionalBits(n) {
    return ((n - (n | 0)) * 0x100000000) | 0;
}
```

The function is taken from [here](https://github.com/jakubzapletal/crypto-js/blob/master/src/sha256.js).

What I've ended up with is fairly straightforward:

```
Public Shared Function GetFractionalBits(n As Double) As Long
    Return (((n Or 0) - 1) * &H100000000) Or 0
End Function
```

Note that I changed `n - (n | 0)` to `n - ((n Or 0) - 1)`, because I noticed that the result in VB.NET differed by 1. Admittedly, I'm not sure why.

For many inputs, it gives the same result as the JavaScript function. However, for some inputs, the result I get is one off of what it should be. For example, `78.9` returns `-429496730` in both cases, but `78.6` returns `-1717986918` in VB.NET and `-1717986919` in JavaScript. In all of the test cases I've tried, it's never off by more than 1.

I decided to investigate, and found the expressions mentioned earlier, `n - (n | 0)` and `n - ((n Or 0) - 1)` were returning ever so slightly different values-- In JavaScript, the first one returns `0.5999999999999943`. In VB.NET, the second one returns `0.599999999999994`. It seems that it's *slightly* less precise despite both being 64-bit floating point numbers.

I tried getting the fractional part in another, simpler way, by doing `n - Math.Floor(n)`. However, it's no more accurate; the last 3 is still missing.

What might I be doing wrong?

Comment: This is just a wild guess, but have you tried to change `n As Decimal` to `n As Double` ?

Comment: Actually, yes. I was modifying it as I typed up this question and forgot to change the question reflect that. I've updated it now.

Comment: I've got the same results you had with both an exact port of JS function `((n - (n or 0)) * &H100000000) or 0` and the other approach `(n - math.Ceiling(n)) * &H100000000`. I can see no other explanation than a different way of processing these calculations between JS and .NET Framework, which appears in the limit of precision.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your example result with Option Strict Off. The code does not compile with Option Strict On, so I can only guess that there are more variable type mismatches elsewhere in the code. You state that you used `n - ((n Or 0) - 1)`, but that is not in the code shown (I tried both nevertheless). Perhaps the [BitConverter.GetBytes Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a5be4sc9(v=vs.110).aspx) would be of use to you.